# Node Mysql Pool Not Ending / Closing

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

Am I missing something here?  This should work fine, but I find that Node run loop stays active.

```
var mysql   = require('mysql');

//Setup Connections and Parser
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'me',
    password : '12345',
    database : 'A2014',
    connectionLimit: 100
});

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

    connection.query( 'select count(9) from mytbl;', function(err, rows) {
        connection.release();
    });

});

pool.end();
```

Comment: move the `pool.end()` to inside the pool.getConnection function

Comment: Thanks, @fmodos, you're right.  But what if I have multiple getConnection blocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var mysql   = require('mysql');

//Setup Connections and Parser
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'me',
    password : '12345',
    database : 'A2014',
    connectionLimit: 100
});

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

    connection.query( 'select count(9) from mytbl;', function(err, rows) {
        connection.release();
    });
    pool.end();
});
```